# add sphere in rgl

Tags: r, 3d, rgl

I am trying to add a sphere in a 3D graphs with `rgl` but I cannot manage to get what I want. 
My data looks like that:

```
L     a     b    
89.09 -0.78 66.41    
89.41 -0.55 61.08    
89.18 -0.46 61.86
```

First I plot my points using the `plot3d`

```
open3d()    
plot3d(data)
```

Then for one specific point I would like to add a sphere with a radius of 1:

```
spheres3d(dataforonepoint,radius=1,alpha=0.5)
```

The issue is that the sphere is not using the coordinate, based on the data it should actually not look like a sphere as the axis are not in the same scale.

[image]

Comment: I don't get what the problem is.
`sphere3d` creates a sphere of radius 1 around the given coordinates, in this case around `dataforonepoint` that your are not giving us.

Comment: In the example, the sphere is not with a radius of 1 as it goes from -5.4 to -4.8 when the 2 others coordinates are constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix the aspect ratio between the 3 dimensions:

```
plot3d(data, aspect = F)
```

From the doc:

> aspect: either a logical indicating whether to adjust the aspect ratio, or a new ratio.

Comment: That's exactly what i was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

G Gamba is right for a sphere that looks like a sphere.

If you want a sphere that is geometrically correct in a non-isometric scale (so it won't look like a sphere), you can use ellipse3d() to draw it.  For example,

```
data <- cbind(rnorm(10), rnorm(10), 2*rnorm(10))
plot3d(data)
shade3d(ellipse3d(diag(3), centre = data[1,], t = 1), alpha = 0.5)
```